# mysql find all the possible combinations of one column

Tags: mysql

I have the table UserContacts with a column like

### contact_id

- 1
- 5
- 6

and I want to get the following result (which is all the possible pair combinations of the values of that column)... 
(1,5),(1,6),(5,6)

is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, make a self-join:

```
SELECT a.contact_id a, b.contact_id b
FROM   UserContacts a
  JOIN UserContacts b ON b.contact_id > a.contact_id
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6746b/1/0).

Comment: yeah, that's perfect.. it was so simple. Thanks

Comment: I know this is an old answer but how would you extend this solutions to create unique combinations of more than two unique columns  -  to three, four, or five columns?

Comment: @Edward: you’d need to join the table once for each column, and relate the columns in turn eg `a > b` and `b > c` etc.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
SELECT t2.contact_id,t1.contact_id FROM UserContacts t1 JOIN UserContacts t2 
WHERE t1.contact_id <> t2.contact_id
```

Answer (score -2):

USE CROSS JOIN

SELECT a.contact_id 
FROM   UserContacts a
  CROSS JOIN UserContacts b