# How best to store and index all unique combinations of multiple integers in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, combinations

I need to run a process against unique combinations of 3 to 8 values from a list of 25 integers. This creates a table with approximately 6-million unique record/options (assuming I limit queries as in the following chart) . The formula for unique combinations (here in excel form) for combinations of 8 from a 25 item row is = fact(25)/(fact(8)*fact(25-8)) ...
See this explanation here ... https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/x9e81a4f98389efdf:prob-comb/x9e81a4f98389efdf:combinations/v/handshaking-combinations

[image: ![Unique Combinations]

As I want combinations of 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, or 8 - some records will have null entries for their fourth, through eighth values.

As multiple computers and processors might be working on this simultaneously, I need to store the list of "jobs" in MYSQL and update or delete each record when processed.

Using @[Eggyal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509413/mysql-find-all-the-possible-combinations-of-one-column)'s solution. I can create a table for my 25 values and generate all unique combinations in MYSQL. This list of 25 to 50 values changes occasionally ...

```
CREATE TABLE UserContacts
    (`contact_id` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO UserContacts
    (`contact_id`)
VALUES
    (1),
    (5),
    (6)
;
```

To get all combinations, I can run ...

```
SELECT a.contact_id a, b.contact_id b, ... (I need up 6 of these combinations)
FROM   UserContacts a
  JOIN UserContacts b ON b.contact_id > a.contact_id
```

[See it on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6746b/1/0) (change to MySQL 5.6 db for it to work).

My question is:

1. How to best add this data to a new MYSQL table that indexes these combinations properly, so I can find and update records from this table of millions of combinations?
2. Is it faster to create a compound primary key PRIMARY KEY (firstval, secondval, thirdval ...) ? If yes, how would a select or where query look for the compound solution? etc.

   CREATE TABLE 'combinations' (

   ```
      'combo_id' INT NOT NULL,

      'firstval' SMALLINT(5) NULL,
      'secondval' SMALLINT(5) NULL,
      'thirdval' SMALLINT(5) NULL,
      'fourthval' SMALLINT(5) NULL,
      'fifthval' SMALLINT(5) NULL,
      'sixthval' SMALLINT(5) NULL,
      'seventhval' SMALLINT(5) NULL,
      'eightthval' SMALLINT(5) NULL,

      `started` TINYINT(1) NULL,
      `score` TINYINT(3) NULL,
      `added` DATETIME NULL,
      `processed` DATETIME NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`combo_id`)
    )
    ;
   ```

Comment: 50^8 is around 39 billion rows. Are you sure you want a table with that many rows?

Comment: @TheImpaler I clearly didn't do the math on that. I think the best I can hope for is 15 values with 6 combinations = @ 3 million options  =fact(15)/fact(15-6). Will adjust the question; thanks for catching this ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a queue with millions of rows, you may find that the overhead of enqueuing and dequeuing adds complexity and slows down the processing.

Since you know exactly what combinations need to be processed, I suggest that you simply tell each 'worker' what set of combinations to work on.

**Ways to split**

Let's say you decide to have 10 'worker' processes.

- If there is an `id` that is mostly compact, compute ranges of `id` to provide to each worker.
- Assign 0 through 9 to the 10 workers, then have a worker do id % 10 to see if it is a task to work on.
- A work grabs, say, 20 unassigned ids and assigns those rows to itself.  This is handy if there is no useful pattern for `id` and the list of tasks is continually being augmented.  A drawback is that if a worker dies before finishing its 20, then a separate "reaper" process is needed to put those rows back into the pool of tasks waiting for assignment.

Comment: This is a common sense approach that I looked for first. I couldn't find a python solution that divided up a million combinations - say into 50k list parcels of work (this is a day's worth of work).  For practicality's sake, I need to stop and start jobs frequently as well, so having a properly indexed dbtable of combinations works well despite the temporary wasted disk space...

Answer (score 0):

For storing combinations in a MYSQL database, the solution that appears to work best is to create two indexes :

1. A primary KEY
2. A second UNIQUE index across all combination values - as follows:

   CREATE TABLE `combo` (

   ```
   `combo_id` INT NOT NULL,

   `one` SMALLINT(5) NULL,
   `two` SMALLINT(5) NULL,
   `three` SMALLINT(5) NULL,
   `four` SMALLINT(5) NULL,
   `five` SMALLINT(5) NULL,
   `six` SMALLINT(5) NULL,
   `seven` SMALLINT(5) NULL,
   `eight` SMALLINT(5) NULL,

   `processed` DATETIME NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY (`combo_id`),
   UNIQUE KEY(`one`, `two`, `three`, `four`, `five`, `six`, `seven`, `eight`)
   ```

   )
   ;

Simple solution that works well...